# Jetty websocket client.start does not there

Tags: java, web, websocket, jetty

I am trying to use a websocket connection and for this I am using the example http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html in this example for client the method start doesnt exist in WebSocket client

```
    import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
    ......
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
    SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();
    try {
        client.start(); //this method doesnt exist
        URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
        System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n", echoUri);
        socket.awaitClose(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {}
```

In this code in the line client.start() I am getting an error the method doesnt exist. I dont get information about this method or stop method that use too.

Anybody has any information about this method or any clues why it tell me that those methods doesnt exist? I am importing 2 classes

Comment: What version of the library are you using ? It seems that this library has been changing often. It is possible that you are using an example that is not compatible with the version that you are using

Comment: This error was beacuse dependency. When you work without maven jetty.websocket needs more dependency , needs more dependency

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `jetty-util-XXXXXXXXX.jar` in your class path.

XXXXXXXXX stands for version, e.g. jetty-util-9.4.4.v20170414.jar